# C++ Access an element of pair inside vector

Tags: c++, vector, containers

I have a vector with each element being a pair. I am confused with the syntax. Can someone please tell me how to iterate over each vector and in turn each element of pair to access the class.

```
    std::vector<std::pair<MyClass *, MyClass *>> VectorOfPairs;
```

Also, please note, I will be passing the values in between the function, hence VectorOfPairs with be passed by pointer that is *VectorOfPairs in some places of my code.

Appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a sample.  Note I'm using a typedef to alias that long, ugly typename:

```
typedef std::vector<std::pair<MyClass*, MyClass*> > MyClassPairs;

for( MyClassPairs::iterator it = VectorOfPairs.begin(); it != VectorOfPairs.end(); ++it )
{
  MyClass* p_a = it->first;
  MyClass* p_b = it->second;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

This should work (assuming you have a C++11 compatible compiler)

```
for ( auto it = VectorOfPairs.begin(); it != VectorOfPairs.end(); it++ )
{
   // To get hold of the class pointers:
   auto pClass1 = it->first;
   auto pClass2 = it->second;
}
```

If you don't have `auto` you'll have to use `std::vector<std::pair<MyClass *, MyClass *>>::iterator` instead.

Comment: Personally not a fan of `auto`.  No downvote tho, good answer.

Comment: @JohnDibling It's great for iterators, it's also mandatory for certain types of template patterns.

Comment: I understand the reasons why `auto` was added to the language.  I'm fine with using it when you have to.  I just think using `auto` when it's not needed is a bit lazy, and could contribute to a generation of programmers that don't really know what they are doing.  I suspect I'm pretty on my own with this opinion, however.

Comment: @JohnDibling I think that'd be a valid concern if it wasn't strongly typed.  However, you have to know what it really is in order to pass it into a function (for example) so I don't think the knowledge required is any less.  It just tidies up otherwise ugly/lengthy declarations.

Answer (score 5):

Yet another option if you have a C++11 compliant compiler is using range based `for` loops

```
for( auto const& v : VectorOfPairs ) {
  // v is a reference to a vector element
  v.first->foo();
  v.second->bar();
}
```

Comment: +1:  I wish my C++11 "compliant" major-vendor compiler supported range-based for loops. :(

Answer (score 1):

You can access the elements of pairs inside vector in `C++17` in a following style by combining [range-based](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) `for` loop and [structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding). Example:

```
for (auto& [x, y] : pts) {
    cin >> x >> y;
}
```

where `pts` is a vector of pairs. `&` is used to make *formal* "uniquely-named variable" `e` of structured binding a *reference* so that `x` and `y` referring to subobjects of `e` refer to original pair inside `pts`, which can be modified this way (e.g. `cin` can be used to input to it). Without `&`, `e` would be a copy (to subobjects of which `x` and `y` again refer). Example using your `VectorOfPairs`:

```
for (auto [pFirst, pSecond] : VectorOfPairs ) {
    // ...
}
```

Also you can make `e` a reference to const when modification through structured binding is not needed and you want to avoid potentially expensive copy of a pair (though this should not be a problem in your case since pair object consisting of 2 pointers is pretty small and cheap to copy). Example:

```
for (const auto& [pFirst, pSecond] : VectorOfPairs ) {
    // ...
}
```